# Multiple classes for loops to add numbers

Tags: java, class, loops, for-loop, methods

I wanted a program that asks a user to input a number and based on that number, it will go through as many iterations as I inputed. Then I will ask the user to input either 1 or 2. I want a program that calls on another class that does the calculations where it adds up how many times they say one and how many times they say two. I have most of the code to the point where it will only display the count once, not the total count for each number after it goes through the number of iterations I inputed. I know how to do this in a one class but for some reason it doesn't work for me in two classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully I explained it enough for you guys.

Comment: please post your attempt code?

Comment: please Show us your tried code.

Comment: is this what you thinking my friend ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using two methods in the second class to calculate the total. oneSelected and twoSelected for example. When the user selects 1, invoke the oneSelected method which will increment a counter of the number of times 1 was selected. Do the same for 2. Also have an additional method that prints out the number of times that 1 and 2 were selected and then invoke that method when the first class is finished running.

Comment: Should I call on the second class in the for loop or outside? When I try and call the second class outside the for loop, it says it cannot be resolved